# How could I use Index/Rows formula to combine multiple rows of data across columns?

Tags: excel

Say I have data like this in range (a2:a5), but that's just for one employee

`date`

`location`

`salary`

`manager name`

and I want it like this : `date` `location` `salary` `manager name` in row 1, how would I utilize `INDEX/ROW` formula to have it transpose like that if the range is fixed to 4 rows for every employee?

I have 1000's of emplyoees and need the data transposed easily and my only method now is creating a separate template and concatenating a unique key/ using an index match to pull in that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the formula as below

[image]

Formula in the cell D3 is `=INDEX($B$3:$B$18,(ROW()-3)*4+D$2)`

Formula in cell I3 is `=INDEX($C$3:$C$18,(ROW()-3)*4)`

In ROW()-3 i have used 3, but you have to use the row number where you will insert the formula.

Comment: Ok, separate question, what if the data export has an employee ID in column C, same ID number for all 4 rows until the next block of employee data. How would I have that populate in there as well? I just need it transposed into the columns

Comment: as in, what if the employee ID's need to be in each transposed row, but they're not lumped into the data that I need to transpose, they're in Column C instead. So I'll need to extract an employee ID and tack it on as well